# How to toggle back to original state on click of HTML image map

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do a simple toggle on an html area map but am having trouble. I have a circular image with seven clickable areas. When I click each area it displays the "active" image pertaining to that section. Working fine. Now I want to click the "active" image and go back to the original image/state. I would think toggleClass() would work but it's giving me issues. Not sure where I am going wrong. any advice would be great! thanks!

tried toggleClass() but not working with html map

```js
// there is seven total images, this is two for example

$(document).ready(function () {
         $('#emotional-active').click(function () {
            wheelToggle(emotionImg)
        });

        $('#compulsive-active').click(function () {
            wheelToggle(compulsiveImg)
        });
       });


        function wheelToggle(img) {
        $(bedWheel).addClass('wheel-img--hide');
        $(img).removeClass('wheel-img--hide');
        $(img).addClass('wheel-img--active');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="/assets/img/wheel-closed.png" usemap="#image-map" class="wheel-img" id="wheel-closed"
                     alt="Graphic">
                <map name="image-map">
                    <area alt="emotional-triggers" title="emotional-triggers" id="emotional-active" coords="125,191,272,34,474,26,394,300" shape="poly">
                    <area alt="compulsive-urges" title="compulsive-urges" id="compulsive-active" coords="483,26,682,34,831,193,556,296" shape="poly">
                    <area alt="planning" title="planning" id="planning-active" coords="835,200,952,362,922,581,667,429" shape="poly">
                    <area alt="binge-episode" title="binge-episode" id="binge-active" coords="920,592,854,803,677,889,650,598" shape="poly">
                    <area alt="physical-discomfort" title="physical-discomfort" id="physical-active" coords="670,893,480,977,286,896,471,694" shape="poly">
                    <area alt="distress-guilt" title="distress-guilt" id="distress-active" coords="279,890,100,799,33,583,319,592" shape="poly">
                    <area alt="isolation" title="isolation" id="isolation-active" coords="33,571,1,363,124,198,287,428" shape="poly">
                </map>
            
                <img src="/assets/img/emotional-triggers--active.png" usemap="#image-map" class="img-fluid bed-cycle--image wheel-img--hide emotional-img" id="emotional-triggers"
                     alt="BED Cycle Graphic">
                <map name="image-map">
                    <area alt="emotional-triggers" class="emotional-section" title="emotional-triggers" coords="129,178,273,18,475,14,399,285" shape="poly">
                    <area alt="compulsive-urges" title="compulsive-urges" coords="487,15,682,22,830,181,558,280" shape="poly">
                    <area alt="planning" title="planning" coords="839,191,950,357,924,567,670,421" shape="poly">
                    <area alt="binge-eating" title="binge-eating" coords="920,580,860,788,678,877,641,592" shape="poly">
                    <area alt="physical-discomfort" title="physical-discomfort" coords="670,882,480,961,286,883,469,680" shape="poly">
                    <area alt="distress-guilt" title="distress-guilt" coords="273,873,100,788,37,577,320,582" shape="poly">
                    <area alt="isolation" title="isolation" coords="30,558,2,349,120,186,289,410" shape="poly">
                </map>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the state in your wheelToggle function and adjust from there. Also, you can chain the add/remove class functions.

I didn't add the bedWheel class as I wasn't positive what it did, but feel free to add as needed.

```
function wheelToggle(img) {
    if($(img).hasClass('wheel-img--hide') {
        $(img).addClass('wheel-img--active').removeClass('wheel-img--hide');
        $(bedWheel).addClass('wheel-img--active').removeClass('wheel-img-hide');
    } else {
        $(img).removeClass('wheel-img--active').addClass('wheel-img--hide');
        $(bedWheel).removeClass('wheel-img--active').addClass('wheel-img-hide');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! only issue with this is when I click one of the sections it works but it is adding another image below the main image. So when I click "emotional-active" it adds the whole image underneath and "emotional-active" is active. tough to explain but I think you understand. I was using the bedWheel variable as the "original" state of the main image.

Comment: Edited! I did the same toggle with bedWheel as I did with img. Does that work?

Comment: still doing the same thing. I'm wondering if it has something do with the html area mapping. I've never used it before, kind of n outdated project I'm working on. You would think the code you sent would be fine but it is still adding whichever area i click the full active image beneath the main one

Comment: If you can make your images available and update your code above with absolute urls, I/we can take a closer look.